# What is the best way to publish my WCF Service Library to EC2

Tags: .net, wcf, amazon-ec2, nuget, publish

**Summary**

I have 2 seperate solutions, a MVC solution which includes my MVC 5 project and a Unit Test project, the other solution is a WCF Service library solution which consist of various other projects shown below. I have a free tier EC2 (Windows) instance running on AWS.

[image]

I already have configured my mvc solution in IIS to use "dev.fleepos.local"for my mvc project and the service project to use "service.fleepos.local". All these works fine. I am able to consume my services from my web solution.

**Problem**

I am able to publish my MVC application using WebDeploy to my EC2 Instance but it will not work alone as it needs the service application, but the problem i am having is that I cant publish my Fleepos.Services solution as whole, I can only publish the Fleepos.Services project (Startup project in the picture above in bold). The issue is I need all these other projects along with it for it to work. I have IIS installed on my EC2 windows server, and my database is on my sql express on there also. I just need my Service Layer uploaded.

**What i tried**

I use team city to run my build after it has been committed to Git and the 2nd build step is to get the DLLs and turn them into a nuget package using a nuspec file which also works fine.

These are the DLLs shown below from a nuget package explorer.

[image]

Now i dont know what to do next. A very detailed explanation will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use project references for the other supporting service projects.  I suspect they are currently referenced via relative DLL references instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx

If you setup project references, then when you compile the service project it will build the others and place their DLLs into its bin folder.  Then when you install the service project it will include all the DLLs it needs.

Comment: Hi although i did this already and used the DLLs in m service host which references the other projects. I have been able to deploy the service host. So i will mark this as the answer.